# Project Euler #25 - Can the performance be improved further?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The 12th term, F12, is the first term to contain three digits.

What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?

```
a = 1 
b = 1
i = 2
while(1):
    c = a + b
    i += 1
    length = len(str(c))
    if length == 1000:
        print(i)
        break
    a = b
    b = c
```

I got the answer(works fast enough). Just looking if there's a better way for this question

Comment: you can use dis to check your versions

Comment: If your code works and you want tips on how to improve it, try out the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: Of course perfomance can be improved. You can solve the problem much-much faster because there is exact formula to compute n-th fibonacci number - https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.4-5.shtml. I guess even O(1) algorithm is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you've answered the question, you'll find plenty of explanations on answers in the [problem thread](https://projecteuler.net/thread=25). The solution you posted is pretty much okay. You may get a slight speedup by simply checking that your `c>=10^999` at every step instead of first converting it to a string.

The better method is to use the fact that when the Fibonacci numbers become large enough, the Fibonacci numbers converge to `round(phi**n/(5**.5))` where `phi=1.6180...` is the golden ratio and `round(x)` rounds `x` to the nearest integer. Let's consider the general case of finding the first Fibonacci number with more than `m` digits. We are then looking for `n` such that `round(phi**n/(5**.5)) >= 10**(m-1)`

We can easily solve that by just taking the log of both sides and observe that
`log(phi)*n - log(5)/2 >= m-1` and then solve for `n`.

If you're wondering "well how do I know that it has converged by the `n`th number?" Well, you can check for yourself, or you can [look online](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emat6680fa09/gonterman/Gonterman12/Fib12.html).

Also, I think questions like these either belong on the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Even [Math Overflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place for Project Euler questions, since many are rooted in number theory.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is completely fine for #25 on project euler. However, if you really want to optimize for speed here you can try to calculate fibonacci using the identities I have written about in this blog post:  https://sloperium.github.io/calculating-the-last-digits-of-large-fibonacci-numbers.html

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib4(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    if n % 2:
        m = (n + 1) // 2
        return fib4(m) ** 2 + fib4(m - 1) ** 2
    else:
        m = n // 2
        return (2 * fib4(m - 1) + fib4(m)) * fib4(m)


def binarySearch( length):
    first = 0
    last = 10**5
    found = False

    while first <= last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        length_string = len(str(fib4(midpoint)))
        if length_string == length:
            return midpoint -1
        else:
            if length < length_string:
                last = midpoint - 1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1

print(binarySearch(1000))
```

This code tests about 12 times faster than your solution. (it does require an initial guess about max size though)